# KOTOR: Why was the Endar Spire attacked over Taris?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I understand that Revan had recently been captured by the Jedi and that, at that point, Malak became the new Dark Lord of the Sith. I also understand that the Endar Spire was attacked over Taris (initiating the plot).

What I am wondering is, why was Revan aboard the Endar Spire when it was attacked over Taris? Were the Jedi transporting him and, if so, to where? Further, why would the Jedi risk having two of their top "students" (Revan and Bastila) on a relatively weak and unprotected transport ship? Also, why were no efforts made to protect Revan from the Sith attack? I am assuming key officers would have know about him and that they would have placed the same -if not a greater- level of importance on him when compared to Bastila?

Everything else in the game is solid, I just can't figure out why Revan was on the Endar Spire and what the Endar Spire would have done had it not been attacked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has never been adequately explained, but we can make some guesses.

### Why was Revan on board the *Endar Spire*?

From the context, I think it's fair to say that the Jedi weren't *transporting* Revan anywhere; the *Endar Spire* was meant to be his assignment. Consider Trask's lines from the prologue:

> **Trask:** We work opposite shifts, I guess that's why you haven't seen me before.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Trask:** You swore an oath just like everyone else on this mission. Now it's time to make good on that oath.

Even if we assume that the Jedi Council didn't know about the bond between Revan and Bastila, it seems likely that Bastila's mission was to keep an eye on Revan, possibly looking for signs of his Sith Lord personality re-emerging, but we can't be sure.

As for why that ship in particular, that's unclear. As a tie-in to *Knights of the Old Republic II*, LucasArts posted an 11-part series of background articles called "Chronicles of the Old Republic". One of these articles suggests that the *Endar Spire* was part of a larger fleet, intending to liberate Taris. The originals have been removed, [but GameSpy.com has a backup of them](http://pc.gamespy.com/pc/star-wars-knights-of-the-old-republic-2/574735p1.html):

> In the skies above the Outer Rim world of Taris, a Jedi battle fleet engages the forces of Darth Malak in a desperate effort to halt the Sith's galactic domination. A band of freedom fighters, including Bastilla Shan, CARTH ONASI, MISSION VAO, and the Wookiee ZAALBAR, commandeer the legendary smuggling ship the Ebon Hawk and make their way with the amnesiac to the Jedi Enclave on DANTOOINE.

However, the "Chronicles" have [many inconsistencies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chronicles_of_the_Old_Republic#Continuity) with the facts of the game, and so should be taken with a grain of salt, although they are considered an official source.

Even if we take "Chronicles" at face value, there's no good explanation about why they needed Revan on that mission. It would be totally reasonable to have Bastila, with her Battle Meditation ability, at such a crucial battle, so it's possible Revan was just going where she went.

### Why were Revan and Bastila so unprotected?

First off, nobody else on the *Endar Spire* knew who Revan really was. Carth certainly didn't, and neither did Trask. There's not a lot of sense in the Jedi Council revealing that information to anyone; even if word didn't somehow get back to Malak, Carth's behaviour when he finds out later in the game suggests that things would have been difficult for Revan is anyone *had* known.

Also, Bastila was not entirely unprotected; we see at least one other Jedi on board the *Endar Spire*, and Trask's dialogue suggests that there are others.

### What was the Jedi Council's plan for Revan?

This is unclear, but for my money the most plausible theory is that they had no plan to train him as a Jedi, they just wanted to use his tactical skills.

Revan is frequently described as a master tactician, to the point that he basically won the Mandalorian Wars single-handedly; Canderous Ordo, one of your companions later in the game and a former Mandalorian soldier<sup>1</sup>, comments on this at one point:

> **Canderous:** It was not [the Republic's] ships or your men or your vaunted 'fight for freedom' that won this, the final battle of the [Mandalorian Wars]. It was by the actions of one person–the Jedi Revan–that you prevailed. Revan's strategies and tactics defeated the best of us. Even Mandalore himself was taken aback by the ferocity, the tenacity, and the subtlety of Revan's plans.

Having someone like that on their side is a pretty big win for the Jedi.

Under this theory, Bastila would be keeping an eye on him to make sure his Sith Lord personality didn't re-emerge. Depending on whether or not the Jedi Council knew about their Force Bond, she may also have been meant to secretly probe his memories for information about Malak's "secret weapon" (the Star Forge, not that the Jedi knew about it at the time).

---

<sup>1</sup> For the uninitiated, Mandalorians are (one of) the *Star Wars* universe's Klingon expys, a meritocratic [Proud Warrior Race](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ProudWarriorRaceGuy), and Mandalore is the best of them. It may not seem like it, but in context this quote is *very* high praise.

Comment: Just a quick question- where did you find the dialogue for KOTOR? or did you just copy it directly from the game? Thanks for the response!

Comment: @GhostKoi In this particular case, from various pages on [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page); they include quotes on many of their articles, and you can sometimes find some gems. In other cases, I go through Let's Play videos on YouTube. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find an online transcript (which, considering the dialogue tree, makes sense)

Comment: Few things: Carth was "only" the pilot not the commander. Bastille didn't know about revan. Revan was on board of the ship as the council hoped that traveling through the galaxy would trigger certain memories that he lost leading them to a clue as to where the sith threat originated from.

Comment: @Thomas You're right that Carth wasn't in command; not sure where I got that from, but he describes himself as an "advisor". Do you have a source for the other stuff? It certainly sounds like it could be a good explanation, but in all my research that's the first I'm hearing of it

Comment: I think it is when they head towards the bridge that the guy who explains you thinks calls carth the pilot.

Comment: @Thomas I clearly don't remember the game as well as I used to; I'll have to watch a Let's Play later. In any case, I was wondering about your claims regarding Bastila and the Jedi Council; do you have a source for those?

Comment: @JasonBaker Have to correct myself there (was some time since I had come to the later parts of the game....I started anew a week ago). Seemingly bastila really knew about revan. will have to look myself where I got the part about them trying to get him to remember.

Comment: I want to add also that the Jedi Council also was likely trying to find out about the starforge from Revan's old memories. They really wanted to know how the Sith was producing so much.

Comment: @Iankill I discuss that in my last paragraph. It's unclear how much the Jedi Council knows about the situation before the game heads to Dantooine; do they know that Revan has subconscious access to his memories? Do they know that Bastila also has access to them through their Force Bond? I agree that they'd want to find out, but because it's not clear that they know they *can*, it's not clear that it's part of Bastila's mission at this point

Comment: It is possible that Revan was just being transported aboard the Endar Spire to the Jedi Enclave and that he was never really meant to serve any function aboard the ship. This would parallel R2D2 and C3PO transporting the Death Star Plans aboard the Tantive IV in Star Wars A New Hope before they were attacked. It seems like the structure and plot of the game were meant to parallel the movies... -T3M4 to R2D2, Bastilla to Princess Leia, Death Star to Star Forge... so on -pure speculation though

Comment: @GhostKoi I suppose it's *possible*, but it seems unlikely. Several lines of dialogue (especially on the *Endar Spire* and Taris) indicate that Revan's implanted backstory involved signing on with the Republic navy for some reason or another (varying depending on which class you choose)